# How to get values from two or more select in jQuery (ajax)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

This is a select & option in HTML. I use jQuery here. I need to fetch the value of both select and pass the values to ajax.php where I need to use both values to check in my database and proceed with another dependent dropdown.

```
<label>Select Number: </label>
<select id= "number" onchange="FetchState(this.value)" required>
      <option value="0">-- 0 --</option>
      <option value="1">-- 1 --</option>
      <option value="2">-- 2 --</option>
      <option value="3">-- 3 --</option>
</select>

<label>Select letter: </label>
<select id="alphabet" required>
      <option value="a">-- a --</option>
      <option value="b">-- b --</option>
      <option value="c">-- c --</option>
      <option value="d">-- d --</option>
</select>
<select id="dependent">
</select>
```

This is my script code written below.

```
function FetchState(id) {
        $("#dependent").html('');
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "ajax.php",
            data: {
                number: id,
            },
            success: function(data) {
                $("#dependent").html(data);
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

I need to pass two values to PHP via jQuery (ajax) to continue further. Here both letter and alphabet value should be get and pass as data in jQuery to ajax.php

Comment: So, you know the `id` of the other dropdown, first check something is checked and then get the .val of the selected item. There literally must be 1000 examples out there if you were only to spin up a DuckDuck search or two

Comment: getting the value is fine, but how to actually pass two values at a time to ajax.php in jquery

Comment: `data: { number: id,alpha: alp },`

Comment: I already tried with it, can't get both values at ajax.php at the same time, but I need to use those in the conditions of MySQL query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The html is a little odd but as you will always have a selection in both dropdowns we could simply do

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
function FetchState() {
    id =  $('#number option:selected').val();
    alp = $('#alphabet option:selected').val();
            
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "ajax_endpoint.php",
        data: {number: id, alphabet: alp},
        success: function(data) {
            $("#dependent").html(data);
        }
    });
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<form method="POST" >  
    <label>Select Number: </label>
    <select id= "number" onchange="FetchState()" required>
        <option value="0">-- 0 --</option>
        <option value="1">-- 1 --</option>
        <option value="2">-- 2 --</option>
        <option value="3">-- 3 --</option>
    </select>

    <label>Select letter: </label>
    <select id="alphabet" onchange="FetchState()" required>
        <option value="a">-- a --</option>
        <option value="b">-- b --</option>
        <option value="c">-- c --</option>
        <option value="d">-- d --</option>
    </select>
    <select id="dependent"></select>

</form>

</body>
</html>
```

And if the dummy ajax_endpoint.php was this

```
<?php
echo '<option value="aa">aa</option>
<option value="bb">bb</option>
<option value="cc">cc</option>
<option value="dd">dd</option>';
?>
```

It should fill the 3rd dropdown for you

Comment: Thank You RiggsFolly, this works well and good

Answer (score 0):

What about declaring an array, pushing to it and then firing the ajax call when you have reached two items in the array?

```
var bothnumbers = [];

function FetchState(id) {
bothnumbers.push(id);
console.log('your array: '+bothnumbers);

if(bothnumbers.length == 2){
    console.log('fire function now that two are chosen');
        $("#dependent").html('');
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "ajax.php",
            data: {
                number: bothnumbers,
            },
            success: function(data) {
                $("#dependent").html(data);
            }
        });
}

    }
```

Comment: Think you misunderstood. I think the OP wants one number form each of the dropdowns

Comment: yeah! this doesn't work actually